# how to Estimates the energy that @pd would consume if @p was migrated to @dst_cpu

Tags: linux-kernel

I was reading the kernel code, how cfs selects the cpu,
In the cpu_util_next function, I think the first half indicates that p is in the queue, so there is an operation to reduce util: lsub_util_positive
However, if UTIL_EST is enabled next, it appears from the comments and code that p is not in the queue; I'm confused about this. Can someone help me explain it
kernel 5.15

```
/*
 * Predicts what cpu_util(@cpu) would return if @p was migrated (and enqueued)
 * to @dst_cpu.
 */
static unsigned long cpu_util_next(int cpu, struct task_struct *p, int dst_cpu)
{
    struct cfs_rq *cfs_rq = &cpu_rq(cpu)->cfs;
    unsigned long util_est, util = READ_ONCE(cfs_rq->avg.util_avg);

    /*
     * If @p migrates from @cpu to another, remove its contribution. Or,
     * if @p migrates from another CPU to @cpu, add its contribution. In
     * the other cases, @cpu is not impacted by the migration, so the
     * util_avg should already be correct.
     */
    if (task_cpu(p) == cpu && dst_cpu != cpu)
        lsub_positive(&util, task_util(p));
    else if (task_cpu(p) != cpu && dst_cpu == cpu)
        util += task_util(p);

    if (sched_feat(UTIL_EST)) {
        util_est = READ_ONCE(cfs_rq->avg.util_est.enqueued);

        /*
         * During wake-up, the task isn't enqueued yet and doesn't
         * appear in the cfs_rq->avg.util_est.enqueued of any rq,
         * so just add it (if needed) to "simulate" what will be
         * cpu_util after the task has been enqueued.
         */
        if (dst_cpu == cpu)
            util_est += _task_util_est(p);

        util = max(util, util_est);
    }

    return min(util, capacity_orig_of(cpu));
}
```

Where was I wrong? Can someone help me explain it